# How to understand what I need to do in a query

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table as such (<sub>Taken from [sqlzoo.net](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial)</sub>),

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| name        | continent | area       | population | gdp               |
+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| Afghanistan | Asia      | 652230.000 |   25500100 | 20343000000.00000 |
| Albania     | Europe    |  28748.000 |    2831741 | 12960000000.00000 |
+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
...
```

and the query is,

> Find each country that belongs to a continent where all populations
>   are less than 25000000. Show name, continent and population

I broke the query as follows,

- Find all continents that have **all populations** less than 25000000 (*subquery*)
- Display the details (name, continent and population) of the countries (*outer query*)     from **these** continents.

When I try to write a query I end up like this,

The outer query seems fine,

```
select name,continent,population from world where continent IN
```

the inner query is making me confused.

```
 (select continent from world where population<25000000)
```

This is not correct as it is not checking if all populations within a continent satisfy constraint (I want to check all the rows within a continent and if all satisfy include the continent name in the `IN` list). //I know how I can do that in `C`//
How do I do that in SQL?

<sub>**Note:**If there are useful links do include them.Insights that explain how exactly a query is executed (Something as clear as 'How a `for` loop works in C - Assign, Increment,Check,Loop') will be very helpful</sub>

Comment: the population limit is on country or on continent?

Comment: @Djerry The country. Each country in the continent should have population less than 25000000 (That's how I guessed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have landed on the [cheat page](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial?answer=1) by <strike>googling</strike> searching online

and it says,

```
SELECT name,continent,population FROM world x
  WHERE 25000000 >= ALL (
    SELECT population FROM world y
     WHERE x.continent=y.continent
       AND y.population>0)
```

<sub>Put it here for anyone referring this question</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Another option to complement fthiella's excellent answers:

```
SELECT name, continent, population FROM world w1
WHERE 25000000 > ALL (
    SELECT population FROM world
    WHERE w1.continent = continent)
```

Comment: nice answer as well :) i don't use `> ALL` often but it fits perfectly here!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT name, continent, population
FROM   world
WHERE  continent IN (SELECT continent
                     FROM   world
                     GROUP BY continent
                     HAVING COUNT(*)=SUM(population<25000000))
```

Subquery will return only the continents that have all countries with a population less than 25000000.

`COUNT(*)` will be the count of all rows for each continent (if there are no duplicates, it will be the count of all countries for that continent).

`SUM(population<25000000)` will be the count of continents that have the popolation less than 25000000, because population<25000000 will return 1 if the condition is true, 0 otherwise.

Or you might also use this:

```
SELECT name, continent, population
FROM   world
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM world w1
                   WHERE w1.continent = world.continent
                         AND population>25000000)
```

Comment: Nice answers. Regarding the first one, I guess it will only work on MySQL as you're making that booleanToInteger conversion :)

Comment: @MostyMostacho tnx :) yes the first one only works on MySQL, but on other DBMS you could use `SUM(CASE WHEN population<25000000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select name, continent, population
from world x
where continent in (select continent
from world
group by continent
having max(population) <= 25000000)
```